# How can i Blur the background of my textview in android studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface, blurry

I have an image with a textview on top of it. I am wondering how I can blur the background of my textview (only part of the image) to make it more readable. I have tried looking at the Blurry library but it seems like it can only blur the whole picture.

Comment: Try below solution, idea is to create a gradient background with dark transparent color. so that text should get visible properly.

Answer (score 1):

Add this custom BlurView solution: https://github.com/mmin18/RealtimeBlurView

Then put your BlurView positioned behind the TextView in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
        <com.github.mmin18.widget.RealtimeBlurView
            android:id="@+id/textview_blurview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/my_textview"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/my_textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text in front of blur view"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, set the blur and color as desired in code

```
blurView.setBlurRadius(80.0f);
blurView.setOverlayColor(R.color.background_blur_color);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use frame layout to produce a blur effect , frame layout  allows to align views along z-axis the last child appears above all other children, example of usage:-

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_height="200dp"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#10000000"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text Here"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</FrameLayout>
```

You can also set the textview background to some color (#AARRGGBB) with lower aplha (AA < "FF" ->max alpha) to reproduce a similar effect easily.

Comment: Are you serious? How does this do a blur effect?

Answer (score -1):

As you want to make your textview more readable as it sits over the imageview. To do this instead of blurring image why don't you use gradient drawable or color.

I had same requirement in my app and I simply went with placing grading view over the part of ImageView.

Let's do this

**Step 1:** Create a gradient shape and put it under drawable folder, let say shape name is gradient_overlay.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:startColor="#BB000000"/>
</shape>
```

**Step 2:** Create a dummy view and place this over the ImageView or part of ImageView.

```
    <View
        android:id="+@id/gradientView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" // adjust the height
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/picture" // give the id of your image
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_overlay">
    </View>
```

**Step 3:** Then align your textview over the gradientView. so that text become proper visible.